# python basic problem in developing raspberry pi 3 GPIO skill

Tags: rpi.gpio, python-3

this is a part of a code for picroft skill:

```
def handle_command_intent(self, message):
    if message.data["command"].upper() == "BLINK":
        self.speak_dialog("ledblink")
```

the "data" and "command" and "speak" didn't define in the code 
how does python found what data is? how about the other?

another problem that i have is in the code below:

```
class iterable(object):
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.values = values
        self.location = 0
```

my question is why haven't location be put in the def arguments like below?

```
def __init__(self, values, location)
```

and why a function like below should be define?

```
def __iter__(self):
    return self
```

The code that i ask about is in [github.com/MycroftAI/picroft_example_skill_gpio/blob/master/…](https://github.com/MycroftAI/picroft_example_skill_gpio/blob/master/__init__.py).

Comment: the code that i ask about is in "https://github.com/MycroftAI/picroft_example_skill_gpio/blob/master/__init__.py"

Comment: Your link has a trailing double-quote that keeps it from working.  For others, the correct link is https://github.com/MycroftAI/picroft_example_skill_gpio/blob/master/__init__.py

Answer (score 2):

The first line of code in your message is a function definition.  The variable "message" is an argument, and so is defined by the function itself.  The function must be called with an object with a "data" property. which will be accessed within the function as message.data.

The "self" variable, by convention, refers to a particular instance of a class.

The example is deeply into object oriented Python.  I'd suggest working through a couple of simple function definitions so that you get comfortable with the idea of arguments, then try defining a simple class and creating two instances of it to learn a bit more about class and object.  Then return to the example.